# IndexError from eureka-flask

Tags: python, flask, microservices, netflix-eureka

So I try to register simple Flask service with Eureka by installing a client. I did everything by the instruction from there: https://github.com/elviejokike/flask-eureka
The code I try to run:

```
from flask import jsonify

from flask_eureka import Eureka
from flask_eureka.eureka import eureka_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
eureka = Eureka(app)
eureka.register_service(name="my-flask-service")

app.register_blueprint(eureka_bp)


@app.route('/model')
def hello_world():
    a = {"text": "I am model service!"}
    return jsonify(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Instead of initializing the service I get this pile of errors:

```
FLASK_ENV = development
FLASK_DEBUG = 0
In folder C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/models-service
C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__main__.py", line 15, in <module>
    main(as_module=True)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 848, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 305, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\app.py", line 9, in <module>
    eureka.register_service(name="my-flask-service")
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_eureka\eureka.py", line 51, in register_service
    eureka_client = EurekaClient(name=name, host_name=host_name,
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_eureka\eurekaclient.py", line 95, in __init__
    host_info = HostInfo().get()
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_eureka\hostinfo.py", line 34, in get
    'IPv4': self.ipv4(),
  File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\models-service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_eureka\hostinfo.py", line 53, in ipv4
    ipv4 = ipv4.split(':')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Every library is installed through pip, code without eureka runs correctly. I think it might be related to OS forbidding an access to network, but I'm not quite sure and need a hand.

Comment: Have you tried separating your code into two files? One for your app factory (e.g. `__init__.py`) and one for flask-eureka (e.g. `my_flask_eureka.py`)? This might be a source of the problem.

Comment: The error you got means that the index `1` is out of range for the list returned by `ipv4.split(':')`. I suspect that they attempt to split the URL into two parts, where the second one is the port. Long story short: It may fail to get your port.